# Derivative of a holomorphic function on a symmetric domain that is real on the reals is not zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be open and connected and with the property that $\bar{z}\in\Omega$ for all $z\in\Omega$. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function such that $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\cap\Omega$. Assume $Im f(z)>0$ for all $z\in\Omega$ with $Im(z)>0$. Prove that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}$ .

This is what i have so far:

Since $f$ is holomorphic, $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ exists for all $x_0\in\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}$ and is the same independent of the value of $h$. So we take $h\in\mathbb{R}\cap\Omega$. Also, $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ satisfies the Riemann-Cauchy equations. Thus: \begin{align}f'(x_0)=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left(u(x_0+h,0)-u(x_0,0)+i(v(x_0+h,0)-v(x_0,0))\right)\\=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left(u(x_0+h,0)-u(x_0,0)\right)\\=&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,0)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x_0,0)\\=&\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{v(x_0,h)-v(x_0,0)}{h}\\=&\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{v(x_0,h)}{h}
\end{align}
Since $\frac{v(x_0,h)}{h}>0$ for every $h>0$ we have $f'(x_0)\geq 0$.

How can I prove that $f'(x_0)\neq 0$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f'(x_0) = 0$ implies that locally $f(z) = f(x_0) + h(z-z_0)^k$ for some $k \ge 2$ and a bijective function $h$. Then $f$ assumes real values not only on the real axis but also in the upper and lower halfplane. That is what @leoli1 said in an answer, which for some reason is deleted again.

Comment: Sorry, my proof was incorrect in the case $k=2$, that's why I deleted it